# Boost::Python. Использование std::shared_ptr в качестве возвращаемого значения метода виртуального класса

Tags: c++, python, boost

Пишу модуль на языке C++ для его дальнейшего использования в Python-программах. Для этого использую библиотеку Boost::Python. Столкнулся с проблемой получения std::shared_ptr из метода виртуального класса. При этом получение std::shared_ptr из обычного класса выполняется без проблем, ровно как и работа с виртуальным классом без получения std::shared_ptr объектов. Вот короткий пример.

Файл Object.h:

```
#include <memory>

class Object
{
public:
    Object(){m_parent.reset(this);}

    virtual void start() = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<Object> getParent(){return m_parent;}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Object> m_parent = nullptr;
};
```

Файл wrapper.cpp:

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "Object.h"

using namespace boost::python;

struct ObjectWrapper: Object, wrapper<Object>
{
public:
    void start()
    {
        this->get_override("start")();
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<ObjectWrapper, std::shared_ptr<ObjectWrapper>, boost::noncopyable>("Object")
        .def("getParent",&Object::getParent )
        .def("start", pure_virtual(&Object::start))
    ;
}
```

Модуль компилируется без ошибок. Однако следующий код завершается ошибкой

Файл hello.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from hello import Object

class MyObject(Object):
    def start(self):
        pass

a = MyObject()
b = a.getParent()
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hello.py", line 10, in <module>
    b = a.getParent()
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: std::shared_ptr<Object>
```

При этом, если убрать чисто-виртуальный метод `start` и изменить код `wrapper.cpp`:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<Object, std::shared_ptr<Object>, boost::noncopyable>("Object")
        .def("getParent",&Object::getParent )
    ;
}
```

то код будет работать.

У меня есть подозрение, что необходимо что-то дописать в ObjectWrapper, но я не могу понять что. Прошу вашей помощи!

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что вы не определили виртуальный деструктор в Object. Также возможно, что этот деструктор нужно явно прописывать в ObjectWrapper. Но это только предположения.